# How do you create a .net 4.5 monomac project?

Tags: c#, macos, monomac

I have 4.5 library I wish to use with a monomac project but under 'edit references' I am getting "incompatible target framework: .NETFramework=v4.5". Is it possible to make a .net 4.5 monomac project so I can reference this library?

Comment: You mean you have .NET 4.5 library? What is the library?

Comment: @Agat: Just another project I am working on and needed to reference. As you can see below, just editing the project file by hand fixed the issue. Thanks for inquiring though

Comment: Did not you consider using PCL libraries?

Comment: @Agat: Cheers, yes I had a look and I will certainly have use for that feature. I just wanted to find out why I couldn't do something that seemed simple in my head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following to the first PropertyGroup in the .csproj file.

```
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

This then allowed me to reference my other .netv4.5 projects